# Outlook Rule to Send Mail On Mail Receipt

Tags: email, outlook, outlook-2010

Is there a way for Outlook 2010 to send an email whenever a message is received?  I don’t want the original email forwarded or redirected (major business rules violation); I just want to receive an email alert at another address. It would be great if that message included the subject and sender but not necessary.   It seems like there should be a rule to do this but I need help creating it.

I thought about using an Outlook rule to call a VBA script to send the email. I tested a couple of scripts but they didn’t work for me.  I don’t think my account has the proper security clearance or the VM environment is configured to not allow sendmail scripts.

[How to send a mail automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9330897/how-to-send-a-mail-automatically)
The accepted answer gives me the following error:
`Line 6:  Adodb.fields
    Arguments are of the wrong type, out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with   oneanother`

[Send Email using VBscript](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/7779b3bb-dfcc-4ab3-966d-9c71d5369ad7/send-email-using-vbscript?forum=ITCG)
The script given at the end of the thread gives me this error:
`SendMail Failed: The transport failed to connect to the server`
and the telnet test step failed as well.

And since I don't want to risk my job trying to circumvent security policy I really hope there is something built into Outlook that will allow me to accomplish my goal.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Auto-Mate Pro, a 3rd party rule add-in for Outlook to do this. One of the rule actions is called "Send Message". There you can choose an predefined template you create for the email alert body. You can also specify the email address to send the alert email to.

www.pergenex.com/auto-mate

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like exactly what I'm looking for.   Unfortunately, I just discovered I don't have necessary account privileges to install programs.  The Programs folder is read-only and the installer encounters an "interruption" when trying to install to a different folder.

Comment: Sorry to hear that you cannot install add-ins. You can still accomplish this using VBA I think. Check this article for reference:

http://www.outlookcode.com/threads.aspx?forumid=2&messageid=29593